# Wordpress Ajax call, can run php function, but not run function outside of that file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've got an Ajax call that runs a function from, say, file1.php and that works fine. But when I call another function from, say, file2.php file it doesn't run and returns an error.

my simplified setup:

```
//functions.php
require('dir1/php1.php');
require('dir2/php2.php');


//php1.php
function func1(){
  echo 'Hello world';
  echo func2();
}


//php2.php
function func2(){
  return 'Hello again';
}
```

Now, func1() is already run on the first pageload. So I know func1() and func2() work fine. But it looks like the Ajax call forgets all the require()s. Because when I change my func1() to this and add the require it works fine:

```
//php1.php
function func1(){
   require('dir2/php2.php');
   echo 'Hello world';
   echo func2();
}
```

At first I thought, meh if it works it works for this call. But now I come to a point I want to call more and different functions from more files. Should I re-require all those files all the time? This feels like the wrong approach. Plus I also want to call functions from plugins I don't know the path of. (I could find out, but that's not the point)

**--EDIT--**
I found out is doesn't re-load any of the required files when running the ajax call. Doesn't Ajax re-run the code including all your code from theme -> functions.php? This has vital code for the call.

Comment: I guess that you could use `include - include_once` instead?

Comment: this will continue executing instead of creating a fatal error - but you might wanna debug the error instead

Comment: do you use add_action() to create ajax and make a call to admin-ajax.php? you shouldn't call the file directly

Comment: @Stender, forgot I had that on already :) it did gave me the necessary feedback.

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski I think I have that part covered. Used the example from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

On the main functions.php I've required an external file called includes.php From this file I require all the files I need in general (not just for func1() ). Whenever I do an Ajax call I first address the includes.php now. This re-runs all the requires. I do have to note they have to be require_once() otherwise it will find the file you are calling it from and crash. It will try to re-declare the functions it already has.

I've got the feeling this is not the most clean way to do it. But I'll have to check this out later, when I have more time to see how WP actually handles Ajax.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, taking a wild guess here, but in the wp-admin.php I'm assuming it evaluates the ajax post request in a clean php process, so it only has access to the function specified and not everything in the symbols table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should call `require` in the file that actually needs that resource. When including `php1` from `functions` it will pull the dependency.

But since you are using wordpress, you should register your ajax functions using [`wp_ajax`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) instead of calling the file directly yourself.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm still pretty new with this, but then wouldn't I require or require_once the same pages a LOT of times. Because I'm reusing a lot af functions from a lot of external files.

Comment: The `*_once` statements will prevent the file from being included again if it's already `included`. If you call `php1` directly the file won't be included from `functions` so you need to `require` it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress ajax (wp_ajax), then this is logical.

Your first code:

You are making the request from the browser link, so the file **DIR path** is correct.
From the current file directory to the file you are requiring.

Your second code:

You are making the request through ajax (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), then the directory would not be the same. Cause, wordpress is just firing the function in this *admin-ajax.php* file and search for your file from that directory.

So I suggest to put a full dir path with the path/to/file.
require(full/dir/path/to/file).

Comment: Ah yea, sorry. I've over simplified this example. I actually have 
require(get_stylesheet_directory() . 'dir1/php1.php'); So it gets the full path.

Comment: Can you just put here the **php error**. I'm a just guessing the problem. Thanks!